# Post request fail in python3+ (sometimes), never in python2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

I try to login to a managed switch (with a static IPv4) using the requests python module, to retrieve the mac address table of the device connected to it (and then logout, obviously). When using python 2.7.10, the login work everytimes, when using python3.4.4, it fails, but not everytimes. I would say that I have 1/3 chance of success.

Here is a sample code that show the problem on my machine (Mac OS X 10.10.5).

```
import sys
import requests

def login():
    return requests.post(LOGIN_URL,
                         headers=HEADERS,
                         data=LOGIN_DATA,
                         verify=False,
                         timeout=10)

def load_table(cookie):
    return requests.get(TABLE_URL, 
                        headers=HEADERS,
                        cookies=cookie)

def logout(cookie):
    return requests.post(LOGOUT_URL,
                         headers=HEADERS,
                         cookies=cookie,
                         data=LOGOUT_DATA)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version_info)
    print("requests version :", requests.__version__)
    login_resp = login()
    cookies = list()
    for req in login_resp.history:
        cookies.append(req.cookies)
    if len(cookies) > 0:
        my_cookie = cookies[0]
    print("errormsg position:", login_resp.text.find("errormsg"))
    # This line will raise an exception in case of login failure
    print("cookie :\n", my_cookie)
    my_table = load_table(my_cookie).text
    print("mac table :\n", my_table)
    logout(my_cookie)
```

Remarks:

- I haven't copy http variable (LOGIN_URL etc.) for clarity. All are correct, I have checked it with chrome developer tools and wireshark.
- The code is supposed to be used in Python3, thus the output in Python2 will be pretty ugly (please keep in mind that it is juste a demo code).
- The requests version is the same : 2.12.4 (latest).
- A `NameError` exception will be raised when the login failed in Python3, cause the response history will be cookie empty. In this case, a `errormsg="login failed. Authentication failed"` will be present in the `response.text` attribute.
- I have try with Python3.6.0 (latest), the fails still occur.

Does any of you have any clue ? Does the bug comes from python3, requests, or the underlying operating system ? Does I miss something in the authentication process (I am quite new to http).

#### EDIT

I have try with Python3.4.3 and requests 2.12.4 under windows 7, and it fail **everytime**.

Comment: How to follow `login path` ? Didn't help you this comment if you type a  `please can you eleborate this` message.

Comment: @dsgdfg I am sorry but I don't understand the question nor what information you want me to add :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after analysing requests bytes by bytes with wireshark, I found that the problem came from the header and the data I provided. In python2.7, the header key and the data key were always in the same order, in opposite of python3.4, which mess up the order of my dictionary.

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#header-ordering) is a small part I miss from the requests docs that talk about header ordering.

Just as a note, here is how I defined my header now :

```
HEADERS = OrderedDict()
HEADERS["Host"] = "192.168.0.10"
HEADERS["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
HEADERS["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate"
HEADERS["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HEADERS["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
HEADERS["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6"
HEADERS["Referer"] = "http://192.168.0.10/"
HEADERS["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

LOGIN_DATA = OrderedDict()
LOGIN_DATA["pwd_password"] = "admin"
LOGIN_DATA["sel_username"] = "admin"
LOGIN_DATA["btnLogin"] = "Login"
```

And the previous code connect **every time** now !! Hallelujah !

If anyone knows *why* I need to do so, I'll be glad to know !